# Cannot reset mysql ROOT password

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, reset

There have been a couple of posts similar to this one already. My problem seems to be unique.

Using this site (http://innovativethought.net/2007/05/17/resetting-your-forgotten-mysql-password/) as my source, I..

1. Stopped the server.
2. `cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/safe_mysqld --skip-grant-tables`
3. `cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql mysql` in new terminal window
4. In new terminal window, type `UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD') WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='root';`

The problem is that I get stuck on Step 2.

```
Brians-MacBook-Air-2:bin Ghost$ cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/safe_mysqld --skip-grant-tables
-bash: cd: /usr/local/mysql/bin/safe_mysqld: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I also might be interpreting my source site incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to search other instruction. For example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I actually found this source.

Might be a slightly stupid question, but I don't have enough knowledge to understand the first step:
1. Log on to your system as the Unix user that the mysqld server runs as (for example, mysql).

How do I do this?